# Status Bar in iOS 8 using Cordova issue

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios8, cordova-plugins

In the iOS cordova app which i am currently developing the status bar is initially hidden.
Within the app i am accessing Camera and Device Gallery in order to get the images.
for Device Gallery

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
                                    successCB,
                                    failCB,
                                    {
                                        quality : 50,
                                        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                                        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                                        correctOrientation : true
                                    });
```

Whenever i access the device photo gallery plugin, the status bar is visible on top of my app.
Tried using [Cordova Status Bar Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar), used the below code for hiding the status Bar.

```
StatusBar.hide();
```

Its doesnt seems to be working.

iOS SDK : 8.1

Any help is highly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the success callback of cordova camera plugin. 
the below code was not getting executed properly.

```
StatusBar.hide();
```

So tried using setTimeout which did the trick as shown below.

```
setTimeout(function(){ StatusBar.hide();}, 0);
```

Please refer [Cordova Camera plugin iOS Quirks](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md#ios-quirks)